# How to modify fetch parameter in git config file using command line?

Tags: git, github, fetch

I know I can use the following command line

```
git remote add pullorigin git+ssh://root@git-xxx.xxxxx.com:1000/mnt/GITROOT/xxxxx.git
```

to change the .git/config and get the following content for that config file:

```
[remote "pullorigin"]
    url = git+ssh://root@git-xxx.xxxxx.com:1000/mnt/GITROOT/xxxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/pullorigin/*
```

However, what I want is the fetch equals to

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Is there any way to use a command line to change the fetch parameter instead of editing the file manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's your use case for naming the refs differently than the remote? Maybe you just want a single remote with different fetch and push urls?

Answer (score 2):

Might it be as easy as this?

```
git config remote.pullorigin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

You're probably looking for a `git fetch` or `git remote` command, which I couldn't find either.